# How to import source code not by giving the linenumber but giving a searchterm

Tags: listings

Has someone an idea how I can import python sourcecode to my document? Right know I'm working with the listings package and providing the startlinenumber and the endlinenumber of my external sourcode. The problem is, as soon the code changes at any position, the reference to those linenumbers in the external file won't be correct any more.

Please have a look at my minimal example below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{filecontents}{testcode.py}
    class Y:
    """
    -----------------------------
    The vertical motion of a ball
    -----------------------------

    Methods:
        constructor(v0)
        value(t)
        formula()

    Attributes:
        v0: the initial velocity of the ball (time 0)
        g: accerleration of gravity (fixed)

    """

    # define (Y) __init__
    def __init__(self, v0):
        self.v0 = v0
        self.g = 9.81

    # define (Y) __call__
    def __call__(self, t):
        return self.v0*t - 0.5*self.g*t**2.

    # define (Y) __str__
    def __str__(self):
        return 'v0*t - 0.5*g*t**2; v0=%g' % self.v0

    # try01
    y = Y(1.5)
    y(0.2)
    print y
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[%
    firstline   = 22,
    firstnumber = 22,
    lastline    = 25
]{testcode.py}

\end{document}
```

As you can see I want to display the function `__init__(self, v0)` inside my document with the corresponding line numbrs in the external file. Till now I have to provide the firstline, the firstnumber and the lastline.

It would be great if I would be able to do sg like:

```
\lstinputlisting[%
    startKeyword   = '# define (Y) __init__',
    endKeyword     = 'self.g = 9.81',
]{testcode.py}
```

or like

```
\lstinputlisting[%
    startKeyword = '# define (Y) __init__',
    linesInTotal = 4,
]{testcode.py}
```

This code should print the function and the corresponding linenumbers of the external file for full traceability.

Comment: See section 6.7 in the listings manual.

Comment: If you wanted to do this without modifying the source you could shell out to standard tools. The difficulty with python in particular is the lack of `end def` -- a function definition effectively ends with the last line containing text indented by more than the `def` line. Finding this involves backtracking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here my solution

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    rangebeginprefix   = {\#\#\#s\!\{},
    rangebeginsuffix   = {\}\!s\#\#\#},
    rangeendprefix     = {\#\#\#e\!\{},
    rangeendsuffix     = {\}\!e\#\#\#},
    includerangemarker = false,
    frame              = single,
    numbers            = left
}

\begin{filecontents}{testcode.py}
class Y:
    """
    -----------------------------
    The vertical motion of a ball
    -----------------------------

    Methods:
        constructor(v0)
        value(t)
        formula()

    Attributes:
        v0: the initial velocity of the ball (time 0)
        g: accerleration of gravity (fixed)

    """

    ###s!{Listing-Y-init}!s###
    def __init__(init, v0):
        self.v0 = v0
        self.g = 9.81
    ###e!{Listing-Y-init}!e###

    ###s!{Listing-Y-self}!s###
    def __call__(self, t):
        return self.v0*t - 0.5*self.g*t**2.
    ###e!{Listing-Y-self}!e###

    ###s!{Listing-Y-str}!s###
    def __str__(self):
        return 'v0*t - 0.5*g*t**2; v0=%g' % self.v0
    ###e!{Listing-Y-str}!e###

# try01
y = Y(1.5)
y(0.2)
print y
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

% by number:
% \lstinputlisting[%
%     firstline   = 22,
%     firstnumber = 22,
%     lastline    = 25
% ]{testcode.py}

% by keyword indicateing start and end
\lstinputlisting[%
    linerange = {Listing-Y-init}-{Listing-Y-init},
]{testcode.py}
\lstinputlisting[%
    linerange = {Listing-Y-self}-{Listing-Y-self},
]{testcode.py}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the experimental features in the listings manual, you'll find something similar to this, see section 6.7.

For a LaTeX book I've used this feature to pull out data between to LaTeX macros (both macros where just equal to `\relax` so did nothing in the LaTeX example. Even if it is marked experimental, it works quite good.